# ColdFusion Multiple cfif conditions only returns the 1st condition

Tags: sql, if-statement, coldfusion, insert-update, cfquery

I am new to ColdFusion and have to make a edit page that will both update and track the changes made to a table; while passing the logged in AD user to the database.

```
Environment:
DB: SQL 2008 R2
OS: Windows 8
Server: ColdFusion 8

Tables Involved:
Branches (main data)
Audit_Branches (change tracking data)

Files involved:  
editBranch.cfm (form)
updateBranch.cfc (updates Branches table)
auditBranchLog.cfc (updates Audit_Branches table)
```

So far I have built the page, and have added the functionality to update the Branches table.  Now, I am trying to track the changes and log the AD user who made them.

I started by using a SQL Trigger to watch for Inserts, Updates, Deletes on the Branches table; but the SQL Server only tracks the current SQL user.  Since that user is a application user, all the users have the same name entry.  Consequently, I re-engineered the Audit_Branches table to have the data inserted directly via CF and thus I can pass the AD username.

Main Problem:I can get the first of three fields to insert into the Audit_Branches table.  If more than one field has a change, only the first one in the Arguments array is run and the others are ignored.

I am using cf-if statements to add to a query that is then being passed via a cf-invoke to the auditBranchLog function.

I have tried nested if, if-else; and and/or statements all to no avail.  Please help me figure out the best way to make the updateBranch go through all the ifs one by one or suggest a better way to pass the information along to the auditBranchLog

Much Thanks...

------------------ editBranch code:

```
 <cfquery name="getBranches" datasource=[...]>

    SELECT 
     BRANCHID,
     BRANCHDESCRIPTION,
     BRANCHFILTER,
     ADDRESS1,
[...]
FROM Branches
where BRANCHID = '#URL.BRANCHID#'
</cfquery>  

<script>

function updateBranch(){
var branchID = $('#branchID').val() ;   
var branchDescription = $('#branchDescription').val() ;
var branchDescription_Old = $('#branchDescription_Old').val() ;    
var branchFilter = $('#branchFilter').val(); 
var branchFilter_Old = $('#branchFilter_Old').val() ;     
var address1 = $('#address1').val(); 
var address1_Old = $('#address1_Old').val();
[...]


$.ajax(
    {
  // the location of the CFC to run
   url: "updateBranch.cfc"
  // send a GET HTTP operation
  , type: "get"
  // send the data to the CFC
  , data: {
    // the method in the CFC to run
      method: "UpdateBranches"
    // send the BranchID
    , branchID: branchID
    , branchDescription: branchDescription
    , branchDescription_Old: branchDescription_Old
    , branchFilter: branchFilter
    , branchFilter_Old: branchFilter_Old
    , address1: address1
    , address1_Old: address1_Old
[...]
            } 
  // this gets the data returned on success
  , success: function doLoad(data) {  if (typeof console != "undefined") { 
            console.log(data); 
        };  location.href = "BranchList.cfm";

                                   }

    } )
}



</script>

</head>

<body>

<cfoutput>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">

[...]

<fieldset>


<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Edit Branch</legend>

<!-- BRANCHID input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="branchID">Branch ID</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="branchID" class="form-control input-md" name="branchID" type="text" placeholder="" 
         value="#getBranches.BRANCHID#" readonly="yes">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- BRANCHDESCRIPTION input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="branchDescription">Branch Description</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="branchDescription" class="form-control input-md" name="branchDescription" 
         value="#getBranches.BRANCHDESCRIPTION#" type="text" placeholder="">

  <input id="branchDescription_Old" name="branchDescription_Old" value="#getBranches.BRANCHDESCRIPTION#"
         type="hidden">


  </div>
</div>

<!-- BRANCHFILTER input-->
<!--- using CFSelect allows to get the db field back for the current selection --->    
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="branchFilter">Branch Filter</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">    
      <select id="branchFilter" class="form-control" name="branchFilter" size="1">
        <cfif LEN(getBranches.branchFilter) GT 0>
            <option value="#getBranches.branchFilter#" selected>#getBranches.branchFilter# (current value)</option>
            <option value="#getBranches.branchFilter#">---</option>            
        </cfif>
        <option value="Branch">Branch</option>
        <option value="Headquarters">Headquarters</option>
        <option value="RDC">RDC</option>
        <option value="Automation">Automation</option>
      </select>

      <input id="branchFilter_Old" name="branchFilter_Old" value="#getBranches.BRANCHFILTER#"
         type="hidden">


  </div>
</div>


<!-- ADDRESS1 input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="address1">Address 1</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="address1" class="form-control input-md" name="address1" type="text" 
         value="#getBranches.ADDRESS1#" placeholder="">


   <input id="address1_Old" name="address1_Old" value="#getBranches.ADDRESS1#"
         type="hidden">


  </div>
</div>

[...]

<!-- SUBMIT Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="SUBMIT"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type = "button" id="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-primary" name="SUBMIT" onClick="updateBranch()">Submit</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

------------------ updateBranch code:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Branches" access="remote" hint="Update Branches">

<cffunction name="getUserID" displayname="getUserID" hint="I pass back the user information in a clean format" access="package" output="false">
        <cfset var UserID = "">

        <cfset UserID = [...] >

        <cfreturn UserID>
</cffunction>     



<cffunction name="UpdateBranches" access="remote"  returntype="string"
    hint="Changes the Branch Info"  >

 <cfargument name="branchID" />

 <cfargument name="branchDescription" />
 <cfargument name="branchDescription_Old" />

 <cfargument name="branchFilter" />
 <cfargument name="branchFilter_Old" />

 <cfargument name="address1" />
 <cfargument name="address1_Old" />

  <cfset auditLog = QueryNew("BranchID,FieldName,Old,New,UserID", "VarChar, VarChar, VarChar, VarChar, VarChar")>     


 <!--- compare old a new and call auditBranchLog.cfc --->

 <!---BranchDescription--->
<cfif "#ARGUMENTS.branchDescription#" NEQ "#ARGUMENTS.branchDescription_Old#">
     <cfset newrow = QueryAddRow(auditLog)>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"BranchID","#ARGUMENTS.branchID#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"FieldName","BranchDescription")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"Old","#ARGUMENTS.branchDescription_Old#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"New","#ARGUMENTS.branchDescription#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"UserID","#getUserID()#")>
 </cfif>

 <!---BranchFilter--->  
 <cfif "#ARGUMENTS.branchFilter#" NEQ "#ARGUMENTS.branchFilter_Old#">
     <cfset newrow = QueryAddRow(auditLog)>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"BranchID","#ARGUMENTS.branchID#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"FieldName","BranchFilter")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"Old","#ARGUMENTS.branchFilter_Old#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"New","#ARGUMENTS.branchFilter#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"UserID","#getUserID()#")>
 </cfif>

 <!---Address1--->  
 <cfif "#ARGUMENTS.address1#" NEQ "#ARGUMENTS.address1_Old#">
     <cfset newrow = QueryAddRow(auditLog)>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"BranchID","#ARGUMENTS.branchID#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"FieldName","Address1")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"Old","#ARGUMENTS.address1_Old#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"New","#ARGUMENTS.address1#")>
     <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"UserID","#getUserID()#")>         
 </cfif>


<cfif auditLog.RecordCount NEQ 0>
    <cfinvoke component="auditBranchLog" method="auditBranch" auditLog="#auditLog#" >
</cfif> 

<cfquery name=[...]
   </cfquery>


   <cfreturn arguments.branchID />


 </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

------------------ auditBranchLog code:

```
<cffunction name="auditBranch" displayname="auditBranch" >

    <cfargument name="auditLog" type="query" required="true">



        <cfquery name="auditBranchQry" datasource=[...]>

            USE [...]


            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Audit_BRANCHES]
           ([BranchID]
           ,[FieldName]
           ,[Old]
           ,[New]
           ,[ChangeDate]
           ,[UserID])

            VALUES
           (

            <CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" VALUE="#auditLog.BranchID#" />
           ,<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" VALUE="#auditLog.FieldName#" />
           ,<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" VALUE="#auditLog.Old#" />
           ,<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" VALUE="#auditLog.New#" />
           ,getdate()
           ,<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" VALUE="#auditLog.UserID#" />

            )


        </cfquery>



        <cfset testVar = "true">

        <cfreturn testVar>


</cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

UPDATE:

Here is the information from the cfdump,  I changed all three values:

```
<th class="query" colspan="6" onClick="cfdump_toggleTable(this);" style="cursor:pointer;" title="click to collapse">query</th>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="eeaaaa" >
<td class="query"   style="cursor:pointer;" title="click to collapse" onClick="cfdump_toggleRow_qry(this);">&nbsp;</td>

<td class="query">BRANCHID</td>

<td class="query">FIELDNAME</td>

<td class="query">NEW</td>

<td class="query">OLD</td>

<td class="query">USERID</td>

</tr>


<tr >
<td   style="cursor:pointer;" title="click to collapse" onClick="cfdump_toggleRow_qry(this);" class="query">1</td>


    <td valign="top">YYZ </td>

    <td valign="top">BranchDescription </td>

    <td valign="top">BranchLabel-New </td>

    <td valign="top">BranchLabel </td>

    <td valign="top">user.name </td>

</tr>

<tr >
<td   style="cursor:pointer;" title="click to collapse" onClick="cfdump_toggleRow_qry(this);" class="query">2</td>


    <td valign="top">YYZ </td>

    <td valign="top">BranchFilter </td>

    <td valign="top">Branch </td>

    <td valign="top">Headquarters </td>

    <td valign="top">user.name </td>

</tr>

<tr >
<td   style="cursor:pointer;" title="click to collapse" onClick="cfdump_toggleRow_qry(this);" class="query">3</td>


    <td valign="top">YYZ </td>

    <td valign="top">Address1 </td>

    <td valign="top">Address1-new </td>

    <td valign="top">Address1 </td>

    <td valign="top">user.name </td>

</tr>

</table>
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>YYZ</string></data></wddxPacket>
```

Comment: `<cfif "#ARGUMENTS.branchFilter#" NEQ "#ARGUMENTS.branchFilter_Old#">` -> `<cfif ARGUMENTS.branchFilter NEQ ARGUMENTS.branchFilter_Old>` Even better: `<cfif ARGUMENTS.branchFilter IS NOT ARGUMENTS.branchFilter_Old>` `IS NOT` indicates this is a string comparison; `NEQ` indicates a numeric comparison. It should be noted that this is for semantics to let you and any other developer know the variable type as the operators perform the same function. The hash tags and quotes are not necessary in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong from a fellow worker bee here in the office.

I simply needed to wrap the cfquery in the auditBranchLog in cfoutput tags like thus:

```
<cfoutput query="arguments.auditLog">

<cfquery name="auditBranchQry" datasource="[...]">
[...]
</cfquery>

</cfoutput>
```

This allowed ColdFusion to loop through the query.

I feel rather sheepish.

Thank you James for your help, it did get me looking outside of the answer I was seeking.

Comment: If you are not outputting any content you could use a cfloop tag and pass the query attribute to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

On this code

```
<!---BranchDescription--->
<cfif "#ARGUMENTS.branchDescription#" NEQ "#ARGUMENTS.branchDescription_Old#">
 <cfset newrow = QueryAddRow(auditLog)>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"BranchID","#ARGUMENTS.branchID#")>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"FieldName","BranchDescription")>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"Old","#ARGUMENTS.branchDescription_Old#")>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"New","#ARGUMENTS.branchDescription#")>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"UserID","#getUserID()#")>
</cfif>
```

```
<!---Address1--->  
<cfif "#ARGUMENTS.address1#" NEQ "#ARGUMENTS.address1_Old#">
 <cfset newrow = QueryAddRow(auditLog)>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"BranchID","#ARGUMENTS.branchID#")>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"FieldName","Address1")>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"Old","#ARGUMENTS.address1_Old#")>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"New","#ARGUMENTS.address1#")>
 <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(auditLog,"UserID","#getUserID()#")>         
 </cfif>


<cfif auditLog.RecordCount NEQ 0>
    <cfinvoke component="auditBranchLog" method="auditBranch" auditLog="#auditLog#" >
</cfif>
```

It looks like you are pushing a query in some sort of ORM Style.

It would be useful to consider

1. `<cfdump var="#auditlog#">.`
2. Having one function for each action rather than a single `auditBranch`
3. Seeing all those `QuerySetCell()` makes me think a different approach may be needed.

**UPDATE**

The following is suggested

```
<cfdump var="#auditlog#">


<cfif auditLog.RecordCount NEQ 0>
     <cfinvoke component="auditBranchLog" method="auditBranch" auditLog="#auditLog#" >
</cfif>
```

Comment: I am using

    <cfcomponent displayname="Branches" access="remote" hint="Update Branches" output="yes"
 
and

    <cfoutput> <cfdump var="#auditLog#" /> </cfoutput>
 

However, I'm not getting any information back.  How do you display information from a cfc generally?

Comment: I don't use `<cfinvoke>` all that much. Normally when I create an object, I keep it around for the entire request. So after I create an object, I would do something like `objAudit.auditBranch(auditLog);`

Comment: I found the answer(see above) but cannot post as answered due to reputation being too low.  Thank you James for your help, it did get me looking outside of the answer I was seeking.

Comment: @JohnySnow - AFAIK, all users should be allowed to post an *answer*, regardless of reputation level. The system may force you wait a few hours to close it, but you should still be able to post it.

Comment: Thank you @Leigh , that is what I meant, but did not articulate it properly.